# Product Recommendation display in email

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to build a product recommendation section in our emails but as I'm very new to AMPScript I'm not sure if I'm on the right path so if you can give me some guidelines would be much appreciated.

This is what I'm trying to achieve 
[image]

```
%%[

set @catalog = [catalog]
set @catalogRowSet = buildrowsetfromstring(@product1)

for @i = 1 to rowcount(@catalogtRowSet) do 
set @catalogSku = field(row(@catalogRowSet, @i), 1)

set @skulookup = lookuprows('PI_UK', 6, 'Sku', @catalogSku)
if rowcount(@skulookup) >= 1 then
set @row = row(@skulookup, 1)
set @ProductName = field(@row, 'ProductName')
set @ProductCost= field(@row, 'ProductCost')
set @ImageLink = field(@row, 'ImageLink')

]%%

SKU: %%=v(@catalogSku)=%%
index: %%=v(@i)=%%
%%=v(@ProductName)=%%
%%=v(@ProductType)=%%
%%=v(@ImageLink)=%%
```

And my Data Extensions

[image]

[image]

The Product1, Product2, Product3... is the ProductCode

Comment: Just a short question: Why dont you use web recommendations call for this? ;) [i know email recommendations seem to be bad because of image generation aspects]

Comment: Thanks for the question. I'm not familiar with that but I want to have full control to the products that I recommend and also to the layout of recommendations. Not sure if I can do that using web recommendations or using Einstein it will pick the products based on its own logic?

Comment: It just offers you a lot more and you can always do injects and stuff like this. Imagine that some customers want to have different products, like people from the USA want PEPSI while people from Canada want Cola. With many more rules like this. I can imagine that you will consider using product recommendations at some point in the future ;)

Comment: We have our own in house tool for recommendations that we are continuously developing. This is the main reason why we choose not to use Salesforce tool

Answer (score 2):

You'll first need to get your Product columns into a rowset.  I typically just build a delimited string out of them, which will give you count on which to base your output loop.  I like to build SKU grids from a loop using the AMPscript [**mod()**](https://ampscript.guide/mod) function

```
%%[

var @debug
set @debug = 1

set @product1 = AttributeValue("product1")
set @product2 = AttributeValue("product2")
set @product3 = AttributeValue("product3")
set @product4 = AttributeValue("product4")
set @product5 = AttributeValue("product5")
set @product6 = AttributeValue("product6")
set @product7 = AttributeValue("product7")
set @product8 = AttributeValue("product8")
set @product9 = AttributeValue("product9")
set @product10 = AttributeValue("product10")

if not empty(@product1) then

    var @products

    set @products = @product1
    set @products = iif(not empty(@product2), concat(@products,"|",@product2), @products)
    set @products = iif(not empty(@product3), concat(@products,"|",@product3), @products)
    set @products = iif(not empty(@product4), concat(@products,"|",@product4), @products)
    set @products = iif(not empty(@product5), concat(@products,"|",@product5), @products)
    set @products = iif(not empty(@product6), concat(@products,"|",@product6), @products)
    set @products = iif(not empty(@product7), concat(@products,"|",@product7), @products)
    set @products = iif(not empty(@product8), concat(@products,"|",@product8), @products)
    set @products = iif(not empty(@product9), concat(@products,"|",@product9), @products)
    set @products = iif(not empty(@product10), concat(@products,"|",@product10), @products)

    set @productRowset = buildRowsetFromString(@products,"|")
    set @productCount = rowCount(@productRowset)

    if @debug == 1 then
        output(concat("<br>productCount: ", @productCount))
    endif

    for @i = 1 to @productCount do

        set @productRow = row(@productRowset, @i)
        set @sku = field(@productRow, 1)

        set @skuRows = lookuprows('PI_UK','skuID', @sku)
        set @skuRowCount = rowcount(@skuRows)

        if @debug == 1 then
            output(concat("<br>skuRowCount: ", @skuRowCount))
        endif

        if @skuRowCount > 0 then

            set @skuRow = row(@skuRows, 1)
            set @ProductName = field(@skuRow, 'ProductName')
            set @ProductCost= field(@skuRow, 'ProductCost')
            set @ImageLink = field(@skuRow, 'ImageLink')

            ]%%

            %%[ if @i == 1 then ]%%

                <table border="1">
                    <tr>

            %%[ endif ]%%

                        %%[ if mod(@i,3) == 2 then ]%%

                            <td>
                                sku: %%=v(@sku)=%%
                                <br>index: %%=v(@i)=%%
                                <br>%%=v(@ProductName)=%%
                                <br>%%=v(@ProductType)=%%
                                <br>%%=v(@ImageLink)=%%
                            </td>

                        %%[ endif ]%%


                        %%[ if mod(@i,3) == 1 then ]%%

                            <td>
                                sku: %%=v(@sku)=%%
                                <br>index: %%=v(@i)=%%
                                <br>%%=v(@ProductName)=%%
                                <br>%%=v(@ProductType)=%%
                                <br>%%=v(@ImageLink)=%%
                            </td>

                        %%[ endif ]%%

                        %%[ if mod(@i,3) == 0 then ]%%

                            <td>
                                sku: %%=v(@sku)=%%
                                <br>index: %%=v(@i)=%%
                                <br>%%=v(@ProductName)=%%
                                <br>%%=v(@ProductType)=%%
                                <br>%%=v(@ImageLink)=%%
                            </td>

                        %%[ endif ]%%

            %%[ if @i == @productCount then ]%%

                    </tr>
                </table>

            %%[ endif ]%%

            %%[

        else
          raiseError("SKU not found", 1)
        endif

    next @i

else
    raiseError("no products", 1)
endif

]%%
```

In this example, if your total product count isn't a multiple of 3 then the last row will be out of whack.   You'll need to address that layout case when you add your HTML.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99149/discussion-between-duicug-and-adam-spriggs).